# Set superpixel color

Tags: python, scikit-image

Assuming that you have the result of a superpixeling algorithm such as SLIC
[Superpixel Algorithms](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_segmentations.html)

```
segments_slic = slic(img, n_segments=250, compactness=10, sigma=1)
```

How can you display the image as being colored differently for each superpixel with a preset color (say, you know beforehand which color coresponds to each superpixel, as in a semantic labelling problem.

I need something similar to

```
imshow(mark_boundaries(img, segments_slic))
```

but instead of just marking the boundaries, I need semantic segmentation with the labels that I work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know which value you'd like to assign to a specific position, say at (i, j), make a copy of the labels

```
new_labels = labels.copy()
```

Then proceed to "rename" the labels:

```
new_labels[labels == labels[i, j]] = new_label_value
```